# Displaying some values from an array VBA excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to display multiple values on my excel file based on first line and first column. I've made a 2D array for my values. MyValue is an `InputBox` variable and I loop over the first column trying to find MyValue and I want to get on display values that are on "**PSC**", "**BCCH**" and so on columns, basically the same thing as a filter based on 1st column but displaying only some values from other columns. The output that i have for this operation is in this image:
[image]

However 136, 144 and 152 which are PSC values are on line 2, 3, 4 in my source excel file, I'm not sure what are those zeros. I want to diplay those values one under each other, I tried without  offset method but if I don't use it I get no value displayed.

```
Dim1 = wSht.Range("A2", wSht.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
Dim2 = wSht.Range("A1", wSht.Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count

For i = 1 To Dim1
    For j = 1 To Dim2
        If wSht.Cells(i, 1) = MyValue Then
            If wSht.Cells(1, j) = "PSC" Then

                ReDim Preserve Matrice(0 To 5, 0 To Matrice_size)
                Matrice(0, Matrice_size) = wSht.Cells(i, j).value
                Matrice_size = Matrice_size + 1
            End If

            If wSht.Cells(1, j) = "BCCH" Then

                ReDim Preserve Matrice(0 To 5, 0 To Matrice_size)
                Matrice(1, Matrice_size) = wSht.Cells(i, j).value
                Matrice_size = Matrice_size + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j

Next i

For k = LBound(Matrice, 1) To UBound(Matrice, 1)
    For l = LBound(Matrice, 2) To UBound(Matrice, 2)
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2").Offset(k, l).value = Application.Transpose(Matrice(k, l))
    Next l

Next k
```

Comment: source file (or an excerpt) would help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. switch the first `If` line with the `For j` and also the corresponding last `End If` with the `Next j`, so the inner loop only runs through the correct rows.
2. it seems the data starts at line 2, so start the `For i` loop with `2`.
3. if you only need data from those two columns you can look for them in a separate loop first and save their position, so you don't need a nested loop. (in this case my first point doesn't apply). 
   you don't even need a loop, you can use Excel's MATCH function.
4. the matrix and transpose seems to be an overkill. since `i` determines `k` and `l` you can get rid of this part, and write to `Worksheets(1)` directly from the i-j loop.
5. you have five rows in the matrix and every fifth output is a correct value, isn't that suspicious?
6. you seem to put values into line *0* and *1* of the matrix then read from line *1* and *2*. this might be the reason for the line full of `0`s

if you can provide what exactly you would expect from what exact source data, I can help you more. but without knowing, my solution would look something like

```
PSC_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("PSC", wSht.Rows(1).EntireRow, 0)
BCCH_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("BCCH", wSht.Rows(1).EntireRow, 0)

For i = 2 To wSht.[A2].End(xlDown).Row
    If wSht.Cells(i, 1) = MyValue Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).[A2].Offset(k, 0).Value = wSht.Cells(i, PSC_col).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).[B2].Offset(k, 0).Value = wSht.Cells(i, BCCH_col).Value
        k = k + 1
    End If
Next i
```